# With gtsummary, is it possible to have N on a separate row to the column name?

Tags: gtsummary

gtsummary by default puts the number of observations in a `by` group beside the label for that group. This increases the width of the table... with many groups or large N, the table would quickly become very wide.

[image]

Is it possible to get gtsummary to report N on a separate row beneath the label? E.g.

```
> data(mtcars)
> mtcars %>%
+         select(mpg, cyl, vs, am) %>%
+         tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
+         as_tibble()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `**Characteristic**` `**0**, N = 19`   `**1**, N = 13`  
  <chr>                <chr>             <chr>            
1 mpg                  17.3 (14.9, 19.2) 22.8 (21.0, 30.4)
2 cyl                  NA                NA               
3 4                    3 (16%)           8 (62%)          
4 6                    4 (21%)           3 (23%)          
5 8                    12 (63%)          2 (15%)          
6 vs                   7 (37%)           7 (54%)
```

would become

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `**Characteristic**` `**0**`           `**1**`  
  <chr>                <chr>             <chr>            
1                      N = 19            N = 13
2 mpg                  17.3 (14.9, 19.2) 22.8 (21.0, 30.4)
3 cyl                  NA                NA               
4 4                    3 (16%)           8 (62%)          
5 6                    4 (21%)           3 (23%)          
6 8                    12 (63%)          2 (15%)          
7 vs                   7 (37%)           7 (54%)
```

(I only used as_tibble so that it was easy to show what I mean by editing it manually...)

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am) %>%
# create a new variable to display N in table
  mutate(total = 1) %>%
# this is just to reorder variables for table 
  select(total, everything()) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = am,
# this is to specify you only want N (and no percentage) for new total variable
    statistic = total ~ "N = {N}") %>%
# this is a gtsummary function that allows you to edit the header
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")
```

- First, I am making a new variable that is just total observations (called `total`)
- Then, I am customizing the way I want that variable statistic to be displayed
- Then I am using `gtsummary::modify_header()` to remove N from the header

Additionally, if you use the `flextable` [print engine](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html), you can add a line break in the header itself:

```
mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am) %>%
# create a new variable to display N in table
  tbl_summary(
    by = am
# this is to specify you only want N (and no percentage) for new total variable
    ) %>%
# this is a gtsummary function that allows you to edit the header
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**\nN = {n}") %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

Good luck!

Comment: That does indeed work! Thanks! Feels a bit hacky though... I was hoping for a built in method (feels like there should be one to me)

Comment: Added an option to put line breaks in header itself using the `flextable` [print engine](http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html)

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I was thinking of! Thanks @kittykatskat!

Answer (score 3):

@kittykatstat already posted two fantastic solutions!  I'll just add a slight variation :)

If you want to use the {gt} package to print the table *and* you're outputting to HTML, you can use the HTML tag `<br>` to add a line break in the header row (very similar to the `\n` solution already posted).

```r
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, vs, am) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(am = factor(am, labels = c("Manual", "Automatic"))) %>%
  # create a new variable to display N in table
  tbl_summary(by = am) %>%
  # this is a gtsummary function that allows you to edit the header
  modify_header(stat_by =  "**{level}**<br>N = {N}")
```

[image]

Comment: Just flagging that your last line should have a lower case {n}, not {N} to get the per-group sample size (your image has 32 in each group).

Comment: That is correct! Oops