# gtsummmary::modify_header() with overall column

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to modify the column header formatting in a {gtsummary} table with a categorical varible (two levels) and an overall column, as in [With gtsummary, is it possible to have N on a separate row to the column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347952/with-gtsummary-is-it-possible-to-have-n-on-a-separate-row-to-the-column-name). I'm having trouble figuring out the correct gtsummary variable name to access the various column names. I currently have a workaround in which I first modify the categorical levels headers, and then add the overall and modify it. However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in a single `modify_header` line. Reprex with various attempts below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

# Shorten trial for examples
trial <- select(trial, trt, age)

# Modify headers
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {N}") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A** N = 200 | **Drug B** N = 200 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |
| Unknown | 7 | 4 |

```r
# Adding overall before modifying stats columns doesn't work with {level} or {label}
try(
  trial %>%
    tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
    add_overall() %>%
    modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {N}") %>%
    as_kable()
)
#> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
#>   object 'level' not found

try(
  trial %>%
    tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
    add_overall() %>%
    modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{label}**<br>N = {N}") %>%
    as_kable()
)
#> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
#>   object 'label' not found

# Adding overall before modifying stats columns does work with plain text
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**THIS WORKS**<br>N = {N}") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **THIS WORKS** N = 200 | **THIS WORKS** N = 200 | **THIS WORKS** N = 200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 47 (38, 57) | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |
| Unknown | 11 | 7 | 4 |

```r
# And with {column} but then gives the gtsummary backend column name
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{column}**<br>N = {N}") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **stat_0** N = 200 | **stat_1** N = 200 | **stat_2** N = 200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 47 (38, 57) | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |
| Unknown | 11 | 7 | 4 |

```r
# Adding overall after modifying stats columns does work, but need to change label separately
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_header(update = all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {N}") %>%
  add_overall(col_label = "**Overall**<br>N = {N}") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Overall** N = 200 | **Drug A** N = 200 | **Drug B** N = 200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 47 (38, 57) | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) |
| Unknown | 11 | 7 | 4 |

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that `all_stat_cols()`, by default, selects the overall column and the other columns. Depending on whether you're assigning a label to the overall or split columns, you'll want to use slightly different syntax.

Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_header(
    update = list(all_stat_cols(FALSE) ~ "**{level}**<br>N = {n}",
                  stat_0 ~ "**Overall**<br>N = {N}"))
```

[image]

```r
show_header_names(tbl)
#> i As a usage guide, the code below re-creates the current column headers.
#> modify_header(update = list(
#>   label ~ "**Characteristic**",
#>   stat_0 ~ "**Overall**<br>N = 200",
#>   stat_1 ~ "**Drug A**<br>N = 98",
#>   stat_2 ~ "**Drug B**<br>N = 102"
#> ))
#> 
#> 
#> Column Name   Column Header          
#> ------------  -----------------------
#> label         **Characteristic**     
#> stat_0        **Overall**<br>N = 200 
#> stat_1        **Drug A**<br>N = 98   
#> stat_2        **Drug B**<br>N = 102
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Maybe others will miss this as well - it took me 30 minutes to realize...

The Overall column has a capital N while the other columns have lower case n. It's right there, plain as day. But, at least for me, I read right through it without noticing.

Comment: FYI I'm the next gtsummary release (next week), the overall column will accept lower case n as well as N.